# Laravel/Eloquent best way to do related search

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What is the best/correct way of doing a related query in **Laravel/Eloquent** when you want to query on a Models related model relationship?

**For example:**

> Books have many Printings
> Printings have a Publishers

I want to **find all Books** from a given **Publisher**.

```
Books:where('printings.publishers', '=', $id);
```

Any advice on how to set this up?

Thanks

---

***Update:***

Is it not possible to set this up in the Model, using the **hasMany/ManyThrough** to create the "magic" getters?

The model looks like this

**Books**

- id
- title

**Printing**

- id
- book_id
- publisher_id
- author_id

**Publisher**

- id
- name

**Author**

- id
- name

Answer (score 1):

Setup correct relationships first. `Book` has many `Printing`. `Printing` belongs to a `Publisher`.

```
Book::whereHas('printings', function($q) use($id) {
    $q->where('publisher_id', $id);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you generally do it:

```
Books::with(['printings' => function ($q) use ($id) {
    // Query on the relationship
    $q->where('publishers', $id);
}])->get();
```

**Edit:**

I misunderstood the question. As @AlexeyMezenin answered, what you're looking for is `->whereHas`.

```
Books::whereHas('printings', function ($q) use ($id) {
    // Query on the relationship
    $q->where('publishers', $id);
})->get();
```